# Howto get freq of count's data in month 1 - 12 in specific year

Tags: sql, firebird2.5

Howto i get frequency of count's data like result below
i want result like this to create dashboard

```
## Data in year 2014
Table 1
Month_name   | Count_value
month1            0
month2            12    
month3            15
month4            5
month5            6
month6            12
month7            9
month8            50
month9            0
month10           0
month11           0
month12           0
```

My DB Structure Like This
cust_name | doc_date 
C001 13.02.2014 
C098 17.06.2014 
C099 05.06.2014
i want to count it group by month.

Comment: We need to know what the table looks like (columns, data types, etc.) not just the output you're expecting

Comment: table structure like this
Table_1
cust_name   |    doc_date 
C001             13.02.2014   
C098             17.06.2014
C099             05.06.2014

Comment: very sorry Brian i'm new for this site..

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Include this as well as the table structure and/or sample data in your question.

Comment: no problem, one last question, those dates are stored as text? the field is not actually a date field?

Comment: Are you sure? The values you posted are not in mysql's default YYYY-MM-DD format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select x.mo,
       count(*) as freq
from ( select '01' as mo from RDB$DATABASE union all select '02' from RDB$DATABASE union all select '03' from RDB$DATABASE union all
       select '04' from RDB$DATABASE union all select '05' from RDB$DATABASE union all select '06' from RDB$DATABASE union all
       select '07' from RDB$DATABASE union all select '08' from RDB$DATABASE union all select '09' from RDB$DATABASE union all
       select '10' from RDB$DATABASE union all select '11' from RDB$DATABASE union all select '12'from RDB$DATABASE ) x
 left join table_1 t
   on x.mo = substring(t.doc_date,3,2)
where t.doc_date like '%2014'
group by x.mo
order by 1
```

This does assume the doc_date field is stored in DD.MM.YYYY format like you posted.

I used a left join w/ an inline view that selects '01' through '12' so that months with no docs will still come back (your desired output shows months w/ zero)

Comment: it error.. Token unknown - line 3, column 25. union.
i used firebird 2.5 what i'm wrong?

Comment: @user3793478 the above would be valid for most databases but I didn't see you were using firebird. It might be that it requires a from clause in every query, similar to Oracle, in which case from what I just read RDB$DATABASE is the equivalent of the dual table, try my edited query

Comment: It also looks like firebird's substr function is actually "substring" so i just changed that as well